# tag in changelog improperly closed

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, changelog

When I was trying to update my project on Github, which has its own page, I got this email:

```
The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:
The tag `raw` on line 888 in `functions/node_modules/eslint/CHANGELOG.md` was         
not properly closed. For more information, see 
https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-tag-not-properly-closed/.

For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:

https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds

If you have any questions you can contact us by replying to this email.
```

The line of code it's referring to is:

```
* aafebb2 Docs: Wrap placeholder sample in {% raw %} (#7798) (Daniel Lo Nigro)
```

I don't know anything about Jekyll, and I can't find any answer that doesn't require me to. Could you help me?

Comment: A repository url can help to spot your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [`jekyll/jekyll-help` issue 40](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/40#issuecomment-329378708)

> At some point in 2017 it became illegal to write `{% raw %}` at the beginning (after front-matter) and `{% endraw %}` at the end of a file.
>   But this only occurs with Jekyll 3.5.2 on GitHub, not the Jekyll 3.5.2 that I installed on my local machine.

If you cannot the Changelog adding `{% endraw %}` just after add `{% raw %}`, check if you can avoid including that file in your project.